Using "never" to strengthen the meaning
From the context (I hope I gave enough context) I'm sure "never" in the following is used to strengthen the meaning (walls being even thicker than described), however such usage is new to me. Except for "never been better", which is more like a sarcasm, I don't recall encountering "never" in such a role. Am I correct about strengthening below? How common is such usage?

Castles and palaces only a mile or two beyond the fireball, be their walls made of stone and never so thick as a man's body, slumped and then shattered.


I think the cited usage was never valid. It's a flawed attempt to embellish a now-archaic subjunctive usage that would have occurred as, for example, The castle walls will crumble, be they never so thick. Which is related to the still-current emphatic usage The walls are ever so thick. And just as you can't say The walls are ever so thick as a man's body, nor could that explicit comparative element have ever been acceptable in the never so version..

Actually, it still occurs occasionally today in the "frozen form" Be it never so humble, there's no place like home. Which again could never be padded out to Be it never so humble as a mouse,....

@FumbleFingers - Merriam-Webster gives never so adverb : to an exceptional or unheard-of degree or extent : especially, particularly though he offered never so much money for our help  Etymology Middle English, from Old English nǣfre swā, from nǣfre never + swā so

The OED has "never 4 In clauses and phrases with concessive force, denoting an unlimited amount. 4.a. late Old English– never so: (with an adjective or adverb) as —— as could be." The only citation from the last 100 years is from Terry Pratchett, who commonly used old-fashioned expressions for atmosphere or humour.

@MichaelHarvey: The cited usage here (and my "frozen form" example Be it never so humble...) are adjectival, not adverbial. (But learners should steer well clear of it, however it's labeled! :)

Its an old fashioned way of describing things.  It actually means that "the walls are not as thick as a man's body".
It is not strengthening the thickness of the walls at all.

OP doesn’t ask about literally strengthening the physical wall, but about rhetorically strengthening a statement.
